# jquery nested list, select all li followed by ul

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, nested-lists

I'm having issues figuring out a specific selector of a nested unordered list's.

I'm trying to add a  to all li only if followed by an ul

I'm new to jquery and will appreciate your help.

I tried this which is probably totaly wrong since I'm looking for any a href tag.

```
$("#sidebar ul").each(function()
{
if($(this).has("ul li").next('ul').length)
{
$(this).find('a').before("<span class='my_span'></span>");
}
})
```

Expected output http://jsfiddle.net/7JdEh/
Add a span(class "needed") to any li followed by ul

Here's the markdown.

```
    <div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
  <li id="pagenav">
     <h2>Pages</h2>
     <ul>
        <li class="page_item">
           <a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?page_id=2"
              title="About Us">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item">
           <a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?page_id=4"
              title="Contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item">
           <a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?page_id=8"
              title="Site Map">Site Map</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
     <h2>Archives</h2>
     <ul>
        <li><a href='http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?m=200502'
           title='February 2005'>February 2005</a></li>
        <li><a href='http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?m=200501'
           title='January 2005'>January 2005</a></li>
        <li><a href='http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?m=200412'
           title='December 2004'>December 2004</a></li>
          <li> 
        <ul>
           <li><a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?cat=47"
              title="Stories of our life">Stories</a></li>
           <li><a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?cat=48"
              title="Computer Tips">Computer Tips</a></li>
           <li><a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?cat=6"
              title="WordPress Tips">WordPress Tips</a></li>
           <li><a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?cat=28"
              title="Web Page Design Advice">Web Page Design</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?m=200411'
           title='November 2004'>November 2004</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
     <h2>Categories</h2>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?cat=47"
           title="Stories of our life">Stories</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?cat=48"
           title="Computer Tips">Computer Tips</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?cat=6"
           title="WordPress Tips">WordPress Tips</a></li>
           <li>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?cat=47"
              title="Stories of our life">Stories</a></li>
           <li><a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?cat=48"
              title="Computer Tips">Computer Tips</a></li>
           <li><a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?cat=6"
              title="WordPress Tips">WordPress Tips</a></li>
           <li><a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?cat=28"
              title="Web Page Design Advice">Web Page Design</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.examplesite.com/wordpress/?cat=28"
           title="Web Page Design Advice">Web Page Design</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: you mean like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VqY3e/1/

Comment: Not really, more like http://jsfiddle.net/7JdEh/

Comment: Placing a `ul` directly inside another `ul` is invalid HTML. You'll need an `li`.

Comment: You are right, I know that, just bad copy/paste to show an example. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

These two should do the job.

```
$("ul > li"), and or just $("li").   

Could also do $('ul').find('li').each(function(){
  //code here
});
```

Comment: this will select li following ul.